# Read only the desired column in a csv file

Tags: r, csv

I am working on a Shiny application, in this app i have an init JSON file which determines metadatas as columns name for example. I have a field which is used to select the columns that we want among these. What I want to do is to read a csv file by reading only the selected columns.

I hope someone can help me on this point !
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `select` argument to `fread` from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
fread("thefile.csv", select = c("columns", "you", "want"))
```

for example

```
fread("https://www.everycrsreport.com/reports.csv", select = c("number", "url"))
```